# Maven by example - NullPointer executing hibernate3:hbm2ddl

Tags: maven, hbm2ddl

I am following the [Maven by example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html) guide to learn Maven.

I am busy working through chapter 7, which is a simple multimodule enterprise project containing spring and hibernate. The example files for this chapter can be downloaded [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip), in the *ch-multi-spring* directory.

Sections 7.1 to 7.6 talk about the specifics of each module. In [section 7](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring-sect-spring-running-web.html), the database is generated and the application is run. It is at this step that I receive the following error:

```
> mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl -X
<Some output left out>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Parent Project ........ FAILURE [0.752s]
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Object Model .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Weather API ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Persistence API ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Command Line Tool ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Web Application ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.330s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 24 15:31:18 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:3.0:hbm2ddl (default-cli) on project simple-parent: There was an error creating the AntRun task. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:3.0:hbm2ddl (default-cli) on project simple-parent: There was an error creating the AntRun task.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: There was an error creating the AntRun task.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.AbstractHibernateMojo.execute(AbstractHibernateMojo.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.DefaultPlexusConfiguration.add(DefaultPlexusConfiguration.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.configuration.DefaultPlexusConfiguration.addChild(DefaultPlexusConfiguration.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.util.PlexusConfigurationUtils.setHibernateConfiguration(PlexusConfigurationUtils.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.util.PlexusConfigurationUtils.parseHibernateTool(PlexusConfigurationUtils.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.AbstractHibernateToolMojo.getConfiguration(AbstractHibernateToolMojo.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.AbstractHibernateMojo.execute(AbstractHibernateMojo.java:76)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Since I'm still learning Maven, and not familiar with Hibernate, I have no idea what the problem could be. I haven't changed anything in the downloaded example files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

Here is the summary of my findings:

- the `mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl` command should be run from the `simple-webapp` or `simple-command` folder. (The specification for the plugin should be present in the POM for that module.)
- increasing the `hibernate3-maven-plugin` version to 3.0 will reintroduce the problem, I believe I read some posts that the configuration format had been changed, but I didn't look further into it.
- the `mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl` will report the error shown below if JAVA_HOME is set to JDK1.7 instead of 1.6 (Found solution to this [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/sonatype/topics/9_7_hibernate3_hbm2ddl_fails_not_finding_configurationtask))

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.1:hbm2ddl (default-cli) on project simple-command: Could not get ConfigurationTask.`

Comment: I had the second problem; I tried setting the JDK in my pom to 1.6, but that made no difference.  I finally realized that (duh) when I run maven, it's using 1.7, and that's the source of the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting the same error. 
I modified the version number of hibernate3-maven-plugin plugin:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <!-- insted of 2.1 as documented inside the Maven by example guide -->
  <version>2.2</version>  
  ....  
</groupId>
```

And this fixed the issue. Moreover, I'm using JDK 1.8. Below the 'mvn -v' output:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_20, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```